# Taking a photo with camera results in an image file that looks like a thumbnail on Android 10

Tags: android, image, camera

I have an Android app wrtitten in Java that takes a photo with the camera app and then saves it as a file. Everything is working well on Android KitKat and Lollipop but on Android 10 (Q) the saved file looks more like a thumbnail than a large size picture.

To take the picture, I followed the instructions from the Android developers website : https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

The code to start the intent :

```
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    Uri uri;

    File photoFile = null;

    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
    }

    if (photoFile == null) {
        return;
    }

    uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        intent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

And my code to decode the image is as follows :

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int imgWidth, int imgHeight) {

    Log.e("test image", "debut decodeSampledBitmapFromFile");
    //First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    Log.e("test image", "imgHeight =" + imgHeight + ", imgWidth =" + imgWidth);
    Log.e("test image", "height =" + height + ", width =" + width);

    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > imgHeight) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) imgHeight);
    }

    Log.e("test", "inSampleSize =" + inSampleSize);
    int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;
    Log.e("test", "expectedWidth =" + expectedWidth);
    if (expectedWidth > imgWidth) {
        //if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) // If bigger SampSize..
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) imgWidth);
    }
    Log.e("test", "inSampleSize =" + inSampleSize);
    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    Log.e("test image", "fin decodeSampledBitmapFromFile");

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

Then the code to call the above method is as follows :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Résultat de la capture de la photo
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap imageBitmap1 = null;
            // File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "image.jpg");
            File file = new File(currentPhotoPath);
            Matrix matrix = null;
            try {

                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(file.getPath());
                int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
                matrix = new Matrix();
                if (rotation != 0f) {matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);}
                if(rotationInDegrees == 90){
                    imageBitmap1 = Utils.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 500, 800);
                }else{
                    imageBitmap1 = Utils.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 800, 500);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap1, 0, 0, imageBitmap1.getWidth(), imageBitmap1.getHeight(), matrix, true);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);

            inputPhoto = stream.toByteArray();
```

The logs on KitKat: imgHeight = 500, imgWidth = 800, height = 3264, width = 2448, inSampleSize = 7, expectedWidth = 349, inSampleSize = 7

The logs on Q: imgHeight = 800, imgWidth = 500, height = 3376, width = 5984, inSampleSize = 4, expectedWidth = 1496, inSampleSize = 12

Comment: Actually this code was written by someone else and I was asked to maintain it but I am new to Java and Android. I think the image is decoded to resize it to a smaller size (500 x 800) but I'm not completely sure. Yes I can start the intent to open the camera and take a photo.

Comment: So you let the camera save a picture in a file and afterwards you resize the image in that file and save it again. Now please tell original and final resolution of the image.

Comment: I added the piece of code to start the intent.

Comment: On Android KitKat, the original image size is 2448 x 3264 and it is resized to 612 x 816 while on Android Q the original image size is 3376 x 5984 and it is resized to 281 x 498, so there must be a bug in the decodeSampledBitmapFromFile method.

Comment: It is `inSampleSize which determines how much the image will be resized. And according the documentation it goes by powers of two. So what are the values on kitkat and q? Compare them. You log a lot of values. Put the logging of the calculation of those values in your post. For kitkat and then for q.

Comment: 2448/612=4 and 3376/281=12,014.. hmmm a bit strange.

Comment: You call your function once with 500, 800 and the other time with 800, 500. Log their values too when you put the complete calculations in your post.

Comment: Logs added to my post.

Comment: Please comment on those values yourself.